# the value of iterator %%x is different between echo and set in the for loop in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I met a weird problem during write some Windows batch script: the iterator value `%%X` got changed between `echo` and `set` in the for loop. Here is the code:

```
@echo off

for %%x in (%*) do (
    echo %%x
    set path1=%%x
    echo %path1%

)

@echo on
```

when invoke this script:

```
c:\> test.bat aaa bbb
```

the result is:

```
aaa
bbb
bbb
bbb
```

the first `bbb` is `%path1%`. Could not understand why this value is different from `%%X`

Could anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: ["delayed expansion trap"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Answer (score 1):

The point is that usually your variables are expanded before your code runs so the first value assigned to path1 will remain till the end. To avoid this you have to add `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the beginngin of your code and access path1 with `!path1!` instead of `%path1%`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%x in (%*) do (
    echo %%x
    set path1=%%x
    echo !path1!

)

@echo on
```

This will force the interpreter to re-evaluate the value of path1 at run time.

Check http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html for more information.